# Trailhead : HTTP Post Issue : JSON does not contain correct case sensitive keys

Tags: apex, json, rest, trailhead

I am using Chrome Extension (Advanced REST client) to mock sending/receiving my HTTP payload.

**Request Screenshot**

[image]

**Response Screenshot**

[image]

I am following exactly as per the guidelines given in that exercise and I am not sure why I am getting that error message.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/super_badges/superbadge_integration

[image]

Has anyone encountered this error ?

Answer (score 3):

I looked up some POSTS I had done from Postman.

Authorization has a capitol A, and it is Bearer instead of Basic for the Authorization.
Here is what my header looks like

```
Authorization Bearer 00D2C0.....(Token from oAuth)
Content-Type application/json
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that. Will be interesting to see if it resolves the OP's issue.

Comment: The issue was not related to Authorization Bearer but was related to my content type header info..Instead of "application/json" I was using "JSON"

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I solved it by stetting the below content type code.

request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the JSON payload using JSONGenerator, it will work. Setting content-type is not enough. That alone did not resolve the issue for me. use JSONGenerator.

Comment: please dont post solutions to trailhead challenges, the question above is specifically related to the content-type header in the request.